# SPSS: DO REPEAT with different numbers of matched variables

Tags: repeat, spss

I have a dataset where each case has the following set of variables:

VarA1.1 to VarA25.185 (total of 4625 variables)
VarB.1 to VarB.185 (total of 185 variables)

For each case, VarA1.1, VarA2.1, VarA3.1, etc. are all linked to the same VarB.1.

I want to use a DO REPEAT function to search through each .1 instance using both VarA and VarB.

Example code:

```
DO REPEAT VarA = VarA1.1 to VarA25.185
/ VarB = VarB.1 to VarB.185.
if (VarA = X) AND ((VarB-Y)<0)
VarC = Z.
END REPEAT.
EXE.
```

However, it seems that because there are different numbers of variables in the repeat list of VarA and VarB, they don't pair up. I want to associate each VarA#(1-25).1 with VarB.1, each VarA#(1-25).2 with each VarB.2, etc. up to VarB.185 so that in the repeat function the correct pairing of variables is used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use a `LOOP` on the outside and a `DO REPEAT` on the inside. So here is some example data, with just three A variables that go to 1 to 10.

```
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP Id = 1 TO 100.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
DATASET NAME Sim.

*Making random data.
VECTOR A1.(10).
VECTOR A2.(10).
VECTOR A3.(10).
VECTOR B.(10).
NUMERIC X Y.
DO REPEAT a = A1.1 TO Y.
  COMPUTE a = RV.BERNOULLI(0.5).
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

So here is the part you want to pay attention to. Your `DO REPEAT` currently loops over the 25 variables. This switches it though, so the `LOOP` part goes over the 25 variables, but the `DO REPEAT` goes over each of your A vectors.

```
VECTOR A1 = A1.1 TO A1.10.
VECTOR A2 = A2.1 TO A2.10.
VECTOR A3 = A3.1 TO A3.10.
VECTOR B = B.1 TO B.10.
VECTOR C.(10).
LOOP #i = 1 TO 10.
  DO REPEAT A = A1 A2 A3.
    IF (A(#i) = X) AND (B(#i)-Y<0) C.(#i) = B(#i).
  END REPEAT.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Code golf it is probably not going to beat the macro approach, since you have to define all of those `VECTOR` statements. But I think it is a conceptually clear way to write the program.

Comment: Neat! Haven't ever used a `LOOP`/`DO REPEAT` combo before. Apart from having to write out all the `VECTOR` commands, that would works really well. Particularly so if you have a few or a single `A` variable as in your example and so avoids having to delve into macro language.

Comment: Awesome, thank you both for your answers! As someone relatively new to SPSS I do appreciate the loop/do repeat approach as it makes sense conceptually.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you are trying to do is loop over 25 variables but repeat this for 185 variables.

It would be more intutive to use `SPSS Macros` to achieve this. Stepping through the below will demonstrate the building blocks for solving your data problem.

```
DEFINE !MyMacroName ()
SET MPRINT ON.
/* Generate some example data to match desired data format*/.

set seed = 10.
input program.
loop #i = 1 to 50.
compute case = #i.
end case.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
dataset name sim.
execute.

!do !i =1 !to 25
  vector !concat('VarA',!i,'.(185, F1.0).').
  do repeat v = !concat('VarA',!i,'.1') to !concat('VarA',!i,'.185').
    compute v = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,6)).
  end repeat.
!doend

vector VarB.(185, F1.0).
do repeat v = VarB.1 to VarB.185.
  compute v = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,6)).
end repeat.

execute.

/* Solve actual problem */.
!do !i =1 !to 185
  !do !j = 1 !to 25
    if (!concat('VarA',!j,'.',!i) = !concat('VarB.',!i)) !concat('VarC', !j)=1.
  !doend
!doend

SET MPRINT OFF.
!ENDDEFINE.

/* Run macro */.
!MyMacroName.
```